# Testing a generic return value against default<T>

Tags: c#

Ive the following code:

```
    TConverted ret;
    ret = forward.Get<TConverted>(GetForwardKey(id, convType));
    if (ret != default(TConverted))... // wrong here !
```

the generic Get function returns an item from a cache. It can be a value type or a class. I would like to check if the returned value is null or the default, but the code I guess it should work it does not. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this essentially-identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864243/how-do-i-compare-a-generic-type-to-its-default-value)...

> To avoid boxing, the best way to compare generics for equality is with
>   `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`. This respects `IEquatable<T>` (without
>   boxing) as well as `object.Equals`, and handles all the `Nullable<T>`
>   "lifted" nuances. Hence:
>
> ```
> if(EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(obj,default(T)) {
>     return obj;
> }
> ```
>
> This will match:
>
> - null for classes
> - null (empty) for `Nullable<T>`
> - zero/false/etc for other structs

If this is helpful to you, please upvote Mark Gravell's answer (which I've quoted) on the question I linked to.

Comment: thanks, sorry for missing the answer, I upvoted both your and Mark answer.