# Checking instance of non-class constrained type parameter for null in generic method

Tags: c#, .net, null, iequalitycomparer, equals-operator

I currently have a generic method where I want to do some validation on the parameters before working on them.  Specifically, if the instance of the type parameter `T` is a reference type, I want to check to see if it's `null` and throw an [`ArgumentNullException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentnullexception.aspx) if it's null.

Something along the lines of:

```
// This can be a method on a generic class, it does not matter.
public void DoSomething<T>(T instance)
{
    if (instance == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("instance");
```

Note, I do not wish to constrain my type parameter using the [`class` constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).

I thought I could use [Marc Gravell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/864860/50776) on ["How do I compare a generic type to its default value?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/864243/50776), and use the [`EqualityComparer<T>` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx) like so:

```
static void DoSomething<T>(T instance)
{
    if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(instance, null))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("instance");
```

But it gives a very ambiguous error on the call to [`Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132128.aspx):

> Member 'object.Equals(object, object)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

How can I check an instance of `T` against `null` when `T` is not constrained on being a value or reference type?

Comment: It's been a while since the question was asked, but I'm curious: what's wrong with `instance == null`? According to Eric Lippert's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823239/comparing-a-generic-against-null-that-could-be-a-value-or-reference-type/8824259#8824259) the comparison will simply be replaced with `false` for value types. Is there some other scenario where this does not suffice?

Comment: @enzi I believe that you get a compiler warning (which would be an error if you treat errors as warnings) if it's a struct type (or not constrained appropriately).

Comment: I don't get a warning for a null check on a type parameter that is not constrained.

Comment: @enzi In the case that you can't constrain it to class but want to make sure you're working with a value and not get a `NullReferenceException`.  Think auto generating code from any type (structures or class) and not wanting to change your method name because signatures do not use constraints to determine difference.

Comment: you can just check with `instance == null`, you don't need constraints or a cast to `object`, it just works for class and struct types. I don't get why the question was asked in the first place, merely curious if there can be cases where a simple `== null` _doesn't_ work. As far as I know, it just works and all the complicated solutions here are pointless.

Comment: I know this question is quite old, but I agree with @enzi. According to [this Eric Lippert answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823239/comparing-a-generic-against-null-that-could-be-a-value-or-reference-type) and [this Jon Skeet answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340817/what-should-i-do-about-possible-compare-of-value-type-with-null?noredirect=1&lq=1) simply check `instance == null` works. According to Jon Skeet answer, any compiler warning can safely be ignored.

Comment: Well, since it is the future now, there is a new way to answer this: `instance is null`. As the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/patterns#constant-pattern) themselves say: _We expect to see `e is null` as the most common way to test for null in newly written code, as it cannot invoke a user-defined `operator==`._

Comment: @enzi This is indeed the answer now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a few ways to do this.  Often, in the framework (if you look at source code through Reflector), you'll see a cast of the instance of the type parameter to `object` and then checking that against `null`, like so:

```
if (((object) instance) == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("instance");
```

And for the most part, this is fine.  However, there's a problem.

Consider the five main cases where an unconstrained instance of `T` could be checked against null:

- An instance of a value type that *is not* [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx)
- An instance of a value type that *is* `Nullable<T>` but is not `null`
- An instance of a value type that *is* `Nullable<T>` but is `null`
- An instance of a reference type that is not `null`
- An instance of a reference type that is `null`

In most of these cases, the performance is fine, but in the cases where you are comparing against `Nullable<T>`, there's a severe performance hit, more than an order of magnitude in one case and at least five times as much in the other case.

First, let's define the method:

```
static bool IsNullCast<T>(T instance)
{
    return ((object) instance == null);
}
```

As well as the test harness method:

```
private const int Iterations = 100000000;

static void Test(Action a)
{
    // Start the stopwatch.
    Stopwatch s = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    // Loop
    for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; ++i)
    {
        // Perform the action.
        a();
    }

    // Write the time.
    Console.WriteLine("Time: {0} ms", s.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    // Collect garbage to not interfere with other tests.
    GC.Collect();
}
```

Something should be said about the fact that it takes ten million iterations to point this out.

There's definitely an argument that it doesn't matter, and normally, I'd agree.  However, I found this over the course of iterating over a *very* large set of data in a tight loop (building decision trees for tens of thousands of items with hundreds of attributes each) and it was a definite factor.

That said, here are the tests against the casting method:

```
Console.WriteLine("Value type");
Test(() => IsNullCast(1));
Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine("Non-null nullable value type");
Test(() => IsNullCast((int?)1));
Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine("Null nullable value type");
Test(() => IsNullCast((int?)null));
Console.WriteLine();

// The object.
var o = new object();

Console.WriteLine("Not null reference type.");
Test(() => IsNullCast(o));
Console.WriteLine();

// Set to null.
o = null;

Console.WriteLine("Not null reference type.");
Test(() => IsNullCast<object>(null));
Console.WriteLine();
```

This outputs:

```
Value type
Time: 1171 ms

Non-null nullable value type
Time: 18779 ms

Null nullable value type
Time: 9757 ms

Not null reference type.
Time: 812 ms

Null reference type.
Time: 849 ms
```

Note in the case of a non-null `Nullable<T>` as well as a null `Nullable<T>`; the first is over fifteen times slower than checking against a value type that is not `Nullable<T>` while the second is at least eight times as slow.

The reason for this is boxing.  For every instance of `Nullable<T>` that is passed in, when casting to `object` for a comparison, the value type has to be boxed, which means an allocation on the heap, etc.

This can be improved upon, however, by compiling code on the fly.  A helper class can be defined which will provide the implementation of a call to `IsNull`, assigned on the fly when the type is created, like so:

```
static class IsNullHelper<T>
{
    private static Predicate<T> CreatePredicate()
    {
        // If the default is not null, then
        // set to false.
        if (((object) default(T)) != null) return t => false;

        // Create the expression that checks and return.
        ParameterExpression p = Expression.Parameter(typeof (T), "t");

        // Compare to null.
        BinaryExpression equals = Expression.Equal(p, 
            Expression.Constant(null, typeof(T)));

        // Create the lambda and return.
        return Expression.Lambda<Predicate<T>>(equals, p).Compile();
    }

    internal static readonly Predicate<T> IsNull = CreatePredicate();
}
```

A few things to note:

- We're actually using the same trick of casting the instance of the result of [`default(T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx) to `object` in order to see if the type *can* have `null` assigned to it.  It's ok to do here, because it's only being called *once* per type that this is being called for.
- If the default value for `T` is not `null`, then it's assumed `null` cannot be assigned to an instance of `T`.  In this case, there's no reason to actually generate a lambda using the [`Expression` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.aspx), as the condition is always false.
- If the type *can* have `null` assigned to it, then it's easy enough to create a lambda expression which compares against null and then compile it on-the-fly.

Now, running this test:

```
Console.WriteLine("Value type");
Test(() => IsNullHelper<int>.IsNull(1));
Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine("Non-null nullable value type");
Test(() => IsNullHelper<int?>.IsNull(1));
Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine("Null nullable value type");
Test(() => IsNullHelper<int?>.IsNull(null));
Console.WriteLine();

// The object.
var o = new object();

Console.WriteLine("Not null reference type.");
Test(() => IsNullHelper<object>.IsNull(o));
Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine("Null reference type.");
Test(() => IsNullHelper<object>.IsNull(null));
Console.WriteLine();
```

The output is:

```
Value type
Time: 959 ms

Non-null nullable value type
Time: 1365 ms

Null nullable value type
Time: 788 ms

Not null reference type.
Time: 604 ms

Null reference type.
Time: 646 ms
```

These numbers are *much* better in the two cases above, and overall better (although negligible) in the others.  There's no boxing, and the `Nullable<T>` is copied onto the stack, which is a *much* faster operation than creating a new object on the heap (which the prior test was doing).

One *could* go further and use [Reflection Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y322t50.aspx) to generate an interface implementation on the fly, but I've found the results to be negligible, if not worse than using a compiled lambda.  The code is also more difficult to maintain, as you have to create new builders for the type, as well as possibly an assembly and module.

Comment: +1 Consider changing the `if (((object) default(T)) != null) return t => false` check with `if (typeof(T).IsClass || typeof(T).IsInterface || (typeof(T).IsGenericType && typeof(T).GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))) return t => false`. I think this would be a more explicit way of detecting nullability.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Perhaps more explicit, but not very succinct?  What are the advantages of expanding it to that?  You can also check if it's a value type that is nullable or not a value type (that might make it shorter).

Comment: While understanding the `((object) default(T)) != null` expression requires some amount of thinking, my alternative reads almost like "plain English": "If type of `T` is a class, an interface, or a generic type based on `Nullable<>`..." spells out the exact condition very explicitly. To me, the less thinking is required to understand a piece of code, the better :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I see where you're coming from.  I want to do some research to see that *all* the cases are covered.  However, given that this is what's in the codebase for WPF, I think it's safe to assume that the casting to object check does cover all bases; you have to be *correct* before you're *concise*.