# Why does Assert.AreEqual() cast to object before comparing?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, assert

I'm writing some unit tests and the following assertion fails:

```
Assert.AreEqual(expected.Episode, actual.Episode);
```

If I call this instead, it succeeds:

```
Assert.IsTrue(expected.Episode.Equals(actual.Episode));
```

I had assumed that `Assert.AreEqual()` ultimately calls the `Equals()` method for the type it is given, in this case `Episode.Equals()`.

However, under the covers in **Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Assert** I found the following code (decompiled by ReSharper):

```
public static void AreEqual<T>(T expected, T actual, string message, params object[] parameters)
{
    if (object.Equals((object)expected, (object)actual))
        return;
    Assert.HandleFail...
}
```

This implies to me that the `AreEqual()` method is casting both `expected` and `actual` to `object` to force the use of the base `Equals()` method rather than the overload I have written in the `Episode` class.  The base method will simply check to see if the references are the same, which they are not.

I have two questions:

1. Is my explanation actually correct, or have I missed something?
2. Why would the framework want to force use of object.Equals() rather than an overload of that method?

If it's relevant, here is my method:

```
public bool Equals(Episode other)
{
    return Number == other.Number &&
           CaseNote.Equals(other.CaseNote) &&
           Patient.Equals(other.Patient);
}
```

Comment: Offtopic: which version of ReSharper can decompile?

Comment: I'm not sure how long it's been there but at least v5 in my experience ... the first time you F12 (go to declaration) on an internal object it will ask what you want to do; one of the options is to decompile.  There is also a free standalone decompiler from Jetbrains.

Comment: btw, the method shown is an *overload*, not an `override`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is using `object.Equals(object,object)`, which deals with things like:

- are they the same reference?
- is either or both a `null` reference?

and *then* goes on to use `x.Equals(y)` *after* it has handled those things. It has to cast them to `object` *because that is what `object.Equals(object,object)` takes*. Casting to `object` also avoids some complications with `Nullable<T>` (because a `T?` boxes either to `null` or to a regular boxed `T`).

However, it could also have been implemented as:

```
 if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(expected,actual))
    return;
```

which handles `Nullable<T>`, `IEquatable<T>`, `struct` vs `class`, and a few other scenarios without any boxing.

But: the current implementation does the job, and the occasional box isn't the end of the world (and: boxing isn't even an issue if your type is a `class`).

Comment: Note that [checking for null by casting to object on `Nullable<T>` has a performance impact that can be avoided](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12396457/50776) (it's not your fault, mind you).

Comment: @casperOne indeed, which is why *if I was writing it* I would have used `EqualityComparer<T>`, which **does not** suffer this.

Comment: While this answer is correct, it fails to explain why the OP is seeing false when he expects to see true.  The main issue here is that he only implemented `Equals(Episode other)` and not `Equals(object other)` as well.

Answer (score 4):

In your code you need to override `Equals(object other)` as well (and need to override GetHashCode too).

Just add this to your code

```
public bool Equals(Episode other)
{
    return Number == other.Number &&
           CaseNote.Equals(other.CaseNote) &&
           Patient.Equals(other.Patient);
}

public override bool Equals(object other)
{
    Episode castOther = other as Episode;
    if(castOther == null)
        return false;
    return this.Equals(castOther);
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    //TODO: Implement using the members you used in "Equals(Episode other)"
    throw new NotImplmentedExecption();
}
```

Remember for GetHashCode if two objects are equal they **must** also return equal hash codes. Here is a quick diagram to help visualize.

[image]

You may want to check `CaseNote` and `Patient` for similar issues.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer.  I realise that this is *actually* the reason that my code returns different results for the two assertions.