# How to use a reference type as a key in a document in RavenDB

Tags: ravendb, composite-key

I have a class that I want to use for a document key in [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/):

```
public class DocumentKey
{
    public string Namespace { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

I've also implemented the `ITypeConverter` (not the .NET one, the RavenDB-specific one) interface to convert from the reference type to a string (because in the database, [the keys are all really just strings](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ravendb/RHlIb_k-PrU/WVQG0j8vYnIJ)).

Finally, I've added the implementation of `ITypeConverter` to the `IDocumentStore` implementation through the `List<ITypeConverter>` exposed through the `Conventions.IdentityProviders` property.

However, the signature on the `LoadAsync<T>` overloads on the `IAsyncDocumentSession` implementation look like this (removed the signatures which take multiple ids for brevity. Also, the same as `Load` on the `IDocumentSession` interface):

```
LoadAsync<T>(string id);
LoadAsync<T>(ValueType id);
```

I really don't want to use value types for my keys for the following reasons:

- I have an abstraction which doesn't have a constraint on the type of the key.  Creating separate structures to mirror this just to have value types are *very* inconvenient.
- I don't have complete control over the type by being restricted to a value type.  The value type has a default constructor which defaults the values in a way that I don't want to have to deal with everywhere else in my code.

How can I use a reference type as a document key in RavenDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because all document identifiers are stored ultimately stored as strings in RavenDB, the key is using the overload that takes a string:

```
LoadAsync<T>(string id);
```

From the `IAsyncDocumentSession` interface, you can use the `Conventions` (exposed by `Advanced.DocumentStore.Conventions`), specifically the `FindFullDocumentKeyFromNonStringIdentifier` delegate, which has the following signature:

```
string FindFullDocumentKeyFromNonStringIdentifier(
    object id, Type type, bool allowNull);
```

Here is what the parameters do:

- `id` - This is the object that is being used as the identifier for the document.  In the above example, it would be the `DocumentKey` instance.  Since this is typed as an `object` (and not a [`ValueType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype.aspx)), a reference type will be accepted here.
- `type` - The [`Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) instance that represents the type of the item that the `id` belongs to.  When calling `LoadAsync<T>`, this is `typeof(T)`.
- `allowNull` - This is passed as the `allowNull` parameter in the implementation of `ITypeConverter.ConvertFrom` that is added to the `IdentityProviders` exposed through `Conventions`.

This can all be wrapped up in an extension method on `IAsyncDocumentSession` (or modified for `IDocumentSession` if you want) that is strongly typed, like so:

```
static Task<T> LoadAsync<T, TId>(this IAsyncDocumentSession session, TId id)
{
    // Validate parameters.
    if (session == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("session");
    // Check if the id is null.
    if ((object) id == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("id");

    // Get the string id.
    string stringId = session.Advanced.DocumentStore.Conventions.
        FindFullDocumentKeyFromNonStringIdentifier(id, typeof(T), true);

    // Load using the string id.
    return session.LoadAsync<T>(stringId);
}
```

[Note that the `if ((object) id == null)` comparison can have a performance impact in this scenario.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12396457/50776)