# How to configure NServiceBus with two RavenDB IDocumentStores?

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus-sagas

In NSB 5, how do I correctly configure NSB with autofac container with one IDocumentStore for NSB data and a separate IDocumentStore for application data? I've pasted the relevant part of EndpointConfig below:

```
            // Raven DataStore for Freight system
        var appDataStore = new DocumentStore { 
            ConnectionStringName = "RavenDB",
            DefaultDatabase = "ApplicationData"
        };
        appDataStore .Initialize();

        // Raven DataStore for NServiceBus
        var nsbDataStore = new DocumentStore
        {
            ConnectionStringName = "NServiceBus.Persistence",
            DefaultDatabase = "BookingProcessing"
        };
        nsbDataStore.Initialize();

        // Set up and build AutoFac container
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterInstance<DocumentStore>(appDataStore ).As<IDocumentStore>().SingleInstance();
        var container = builder.Build();

        // Set up NServiceBus
        configuration.UseContainer<AutofacBuilder>(customizations => customizations.ExistingLifetimeScope(container));
        configuration.UsePersistence<RavenDBPersistence>().SetDefaultDocumentStore(nsbDataStore);
```

I know this isn't working since I had problems storing sagas in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26787884/exception-in-ravendb-sagapersister-save-guid-should-contain-32-digits-with-4-d/26798830#26798830). The SagaPersister tried to persist saga in appDataStore, but the Timeout Messages was persisted in nsbDataStore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [sample for 4.x using unit of work](https://github.com/sfarmar/Samples/tree/master/DIUnitOfWork), 
If you use

Look [here](https://github.com/sfarmar/Samples/blob/master/DIUnitOfWork/MyRavenUnitOfWork/MyRavenUnitOfWork.cs) to see how you can implement IManageUnitsOfWork

The Init is [here](https://github.com/sfarmar/Samples/blob/master/DIUnitOfWork/EndPoint/EndpointConfig.cs)
Look [here for the usage](https://github.com/sfarmar/Samples/blob/master/DIUnitOfWork/EndPoint/MyCommandHandler.cs)

will this help?

Comment: Thanks. I took a look at a similar example from Andreas Öhlund earlier. Both examples use only a single DocumentStore, right? So userdata and NSB data are using the same datastore. I'm trying to use two different stores... And btw, u'r sample doesn't compile: The type 'StructureMap.IContainer' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'StructureMap, Version=2.6.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e60ad81abae3c223'. I upgraded structuremap to the latest NuGet version, no luck

Comment: Let me get the sample updated to reflect your use case and use autofac instead.

Comment: Iv'e added a [V5 with autofac sample](https://github.com/sfarmar/Samples/tree/master/DIUnitOfWorkV5Autofac), 


let me know if that work for you...

Comment: (Also commented in NSB group). The sample works, but when I implemented a saga it would still store saga data in the application database, not the database defined by the NSB endpoint. Is this by design? I would prefer to keep everything NSB in the same database away from my application data. Although arguably the saga IS application data...

Comment: It's a bug, and the solution (provided by Szymon) is here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/particularsoftware/B0LSO5MYbpo/7s9toKFlk0QJ

Answer (score 2):

This issue is now fixed in [NServiceBus.RavenDB v2.0.1](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.RavenDB/releases/tag/2.0.1)