# Creating an empty generic object

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I compare a generic type to its default value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864243/how-do-i-compare-a-generic-type-to-its-default-value)

I have a generic function that needs to test if the object that is passed into it is empty or not. But because its a generic type, the compiler doesnt know if a class or a struct is passed. Because of this I cant test for null I have to test if the type is empty.

```
    public virtual void SetFocusedObject(T obj)
{
    //since we dont know if T is a class or a struct test against default
    T defaultT = default(T);

    if(obj != defaultT)
    {
        //code      
    }
}
```

This does not work and its because the compiler doesnt know what T is to be able to compile the test

alternatively I tried the following as well

```
    public virtual void SetFocusedObject(T obj)
{
    //since we dont know if T is a class or a struct test against empty type
    T defaultT = T.GetConstructor(T.EmptyTypes).Invoke(null);

    if(obj != defaultT)
    {
        //code  
    }
}
```

And for the same exact reason, this does not work either. I was hoping that someone might suggest a method that will work.

Comment: What exactly is an 'empty' object?

Comment: the equivalent of default(T)  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: +1 to counter the downvote. It's a duplicate, but it's a good question.

Comment: Thanks for the link, a lot of good information there

Comment: You can test for null actually, but that test will always return false in case of a struct.

Answer (score 1):

That is not a generic function. Unless the function is a member of generic class with a type argument named 'T', you need to declare it like this:

```
public virtual void SetFocusedObject<T>(T obj)
```

This will allow you to use `default(T)` successfully:

```
public virtual void SetFocusedObject<T>(T obj)
{   
    if (obj.Equals(default(T))) return;

    //code      
}
```

Comment: No downvote but, no, your example does *not* compile (tested with VS2012)...

Answer (score 0):

If by empty referece object you mean `null` and when you compare struct with null you get `false`, why not use this as test:

```
    public static void Test<T>(T obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) // default refernce type (which is null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("default!");
        }
        else if(obj.Equals(default(T))) // default value types
        {
            Console.WriteLine("default!");
        }
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        object o = null;
        Test(o); // test detects default
        Test(0); // test detects default
        Class1 c = new Class1();
        Test(c); // test does not detect default
    }
```

Though I'm not sure if you consider `null` default value for reference type, or whether you want to know if default reference type instance is the one created by default constructor.

Comment: It won't, because there is no `Class1` definition, but it's just empty class.

Comment: Now when I've looked at (obviously) better answer in the question mentioned in comments, I see that it won't detect Nullables with default value set.

Comment: yes the best answer ive found so far was if(EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(obj,default(T)))